# Ruby Style Regular Expressions

Tags: ruby

I have used perl in the past and now I am switching to ruby, or rather learning ruby along side perl.

I am trying to extract data from a xml file which has data like this

```
        <outline type="rss" text="w4kfu's bl0g" title="w4kfu's bl0g" xmlUrl="http://blog.w4kfu.com/?feed=rss" htmlUrl="http://blog.w4kfu.com"/>
```

I am trying to extract just the text in between the quotes of text="blahblah" and the url in htmlUrl="http://blahblahblah"

This is my attempt at solving this

```
ruby -ne 'next if $_ =~ %r[text=\"([^"]*)\"]x and print $1, "\n"' file_name.xml
```

I know that ruby tries to be as powerful as perl but at the same time having neater code. This solution seems a bit perl-ish to me and I would like to know what the proper ruby-way would be.

Comment: Did you want it to be a single command line? Or was that just an example. Also, what determines what you want to extract from the XML? Only the specified attributes of `<outline>` elements? It's best not to use regular expressions at all for parsing XML.

Comment: Yes, I did want a single command line. Yes I only want to get the specified attributes of <outline> elements.  I know I'm not suppose to use regular expressions to parse XML or HTML markup, but it was something quick and on-the-fly, and I don't have the nokogiri gem installed or hpricot gem, or any proper markup parsing library.

Comment: It's not typical for a Rubyist to use the command-line options. It would be faster for me to fire up irb and parse the file with Nokogiri. The resulting code would be more robust and potentially reusable.

Comment: and if you happen to be working on a particular computer which you don't have authorization to install new packaged/gems and have to rely on the basic ruby installation? Thus regular expressions (I'm guessing) being the best alternative?

Comment: While this sounds horrible (do you not have access to CPAN either?) I suppose I would fall back to REXML in the std lib.

Comment: my point is, it can be done using regular expressions.  Even though it is advised again, it is a possible way to achieve what I want. My question was essentially, can my Ruby one-liner be compacted any further, lets say for example using the ruby string method "match".  How can my one-liner be more ruby like. Instead of getting the answer I am looking for, I get answers that achieve it in every OTHER way.

Comment: You asked for the "ruby way" but you seem to really want a Perlish way with Rubyish syntax.

Comment: Even you would have to agree that for some cases, Regular Expressions would be faster and quicker than using an external library.  Just because there are CSV file parsers, should I be using those? CSV files are pretty much just comma delimited and would be easier to split the lines at the delimiter, store them in an array and go from there.  No external CSV parser library is needed.

Comment: While I understand your point, this is a particularly bad example, as I deal with lots of data and i will *always* use the CSV gem to parse or create CSV. Too much chance of an edge case like an embedded quoted comma to take a chance on the quick and dirty solution. Also, it's makes for easy to read code. In general, you'd be surprised how little code you need to write and how easy it is to read your code when you take advantage of gems.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend parsing XML with a real parser. It has the advantage of being more robust. For example, it will not false positive if another element happens to have a `text` attribute, and it will accommodate whitespace and newlines in the XML.

Since you mentioned you don't have access to gems (you should work on this :), here's something using REXML from the standard library. It's not quite as clean as Nokogiri but not too bad.

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = REXML::Document.new open("file.xml")
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "//outline") do |element|
  puts element.attributes["title"], element.attributes["htmlUrl"]
end
```

Here it is as a `ruby` command line to print the title:

```
ruby -r 'rexml/document' -e "doc = REXML::Document.new open('file_name.xml')" 
  -e "puts REXML::XPath.each(doc, '//outline').map{|el| el.attributes['title']}"

#=> w4kfu's bl0g
```

But I have a feeling that you really want a regex solution with a more rubyish feel. Here you go:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/text=\"([^"]*)\"/)' file_name.xml

#=> w4kfu's bl0g
```